# Codeigniter - Error while accessing multi dimensional stdObject array

Tags: php, codeigniter

I am getting following result array in view from my controller in CodeIgniter:

```
Array
(
    [cities] => Array
    (
        [0] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 1
            [name] => Jersey City
            [state] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 1
                [name] => New Jersey             
            )
         )

        [1] => stdClass Object
        (
            [id] => 2
            [name] => Philadelphia
            [state] => stdClass Object
            (
                [id] => 2
                [name] => Pennsylvania
            )
        )
    )
)
```

Now I want to create a dropdown box with these values so that the box has city, state.

```
Jersey, New Jersey
Philadelphia, Pennsylvania
```

This is how I am trying to achieve this:

```
<?php 
    foreach($cities as $city) {
        echo "<option value='$city->id'>$city->name, $city->state->name</option>";
    }
?>
```

When I try to access:

```
$city->state->name
```

I get following error:

```
<p>Severity: 4096</p>
<p>Message: Object of class stdClass could not be converted to string</p>
```

I would appreciate if someone could guide me the correct way of getting name out of state array.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're working with an object, but when you `echo` it, PHP tries to convert it into a string and fails, thus generating the above error message. To avoid this, you could wrap your variables in curly braces `{ }`, like so:

```
foreach($cities as $city) { 
    echo "<option value='{$city->id}'>{$city->name}, 
    {$city->state->name}</option>"; 
}
```

Alternatively, you could also use [`sprintf()`](http://php.net/sprintf)  (which is a little bit more cleaner, in my opinion):

```
foreach($cities as $city) { 
    echo sprintf("<option value='%d'>%s, %s</option>", 
    $city->id, $city->name, $city->state->name); 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
foreach($cities as $city) {
    foreach($city->state as $state) {
        echo "<option value='$city->id'>$city->name, $state->name</option>";
    }
}
```

or try this:

```
foreach($cities as $city) {
        echo "<option value='$city->id'>$city->name, $city->state[0]->name</option>";
    }
```